# Show that $\lvert \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2 , \sqrt{1+i}) : \mathbb{Q} \rvert = 8$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

This is the problem $2.2$ of the book *Fields and Galois Theory* by *Falko Lorenz*. It says: "show that $\lvert \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2 , \sqrt{1+i}) : \mathbb{Q} \rvert = 8$. *Hint*: For $w=\sqrt{1+i}$ we have $w\bar{w}=\sqrt2$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,w)=\mathbb{Q}(i,w,\bar{w})$."

I really don't know how to deal with this problem. Any Idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use multiplication of degrees $$\lvert \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2 , \sqrt{1+i}) : \mathbb{Q} \rvert=[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{1+i}):\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)]\cdot[\Bbb Q(\sqrt2):\Bbb Q]$$

Let $x=\sqrt{1+i}$ and find its minimal polynomial over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$
$$x^2=1+i\notin\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)[x]$$ because $1+i\notin\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ but $(x^2-1)^2=-1\Rightarrow x^4-2x^2+2\in\Bbb Q[x]\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ then the degree
$[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{1+i}):\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)]=4$ hence the proposed degree 8.

Comment: I know that we have $\lvert \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(2), \sqrt(1+i)) : \mathbb{Q} \rvert = \lvert \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(2), \sqrt(1+i)) : \mathbb{Q(\sqrt(2))} \rvert . \lvert \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(2)) : \mathbb{Q} \rvert$. but why the equation that you have used is correct? I mean the first one, which says $ \lvert \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(2), \sqrt(1+i)) : \mathbb{Q} \rvert = \lvert \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(1+i)) : \mathbb{Q(\sqrt(2)} \rvert . \lvert \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(2)) : \mathbb{Q} \rvert$

Comment: You use the standard way you use to find the minimal polynomial of $x$ in $\Bbb Q[x]$ i.e. a polynomial $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+....+a_0$ with the coefficients $a_i\in \Bbb Q$ but in this case you need $a_i\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ . Since $1-i$ is  not in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ the polynomial $x^2-(1+i)$ can not be in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)[x]$ so you need to go to degree $4$ in order to disappear the number $i$.

Comment: You are welcome. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $ \mathbf Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{1+i}) = \mathbf Q(\zeta_{16}) $ and $ \varphi(16) = 8 $....

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $\sqrt{a}\in\mathbb{K}(\sqrt{b})$ iff $ab$ is a perfect square in $K$.

Now you have $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(i)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(i,w)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(i,w,\overline{w})$